# Office Script that removes Row based on part of Text

Tags: typescript, office-scripts

I am making an Office Script that should delete a row based on part of the text in a cell in the first column. The trigger word should be "Applied" but it is often more text after the first word, i.e. "Applied formula" or "Applied number".

The Script:

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {

  //getting the used range in the worksheet
  let usedRange = workbook.getActiveWorksheet().getUsedRange();

  //getting the row count of the used range
  let lastRow = usedRange.getRowCount();

  usedRange = workbook.getActiveWorksheet().getRangeByIndexes(0, 0, (usedRange.getRowIndex() + lastRow), 19)

  //getting the values of the range
  let values = usedRange.getValues();

  //getting the row count of the range
  let rowCount = usedRange.getRowCount();

  //for every row starting at the last row, checking if the cell in column 'A' contains part of text "Applied". If it is, then delete the entire row. 
  for (let i = rowCount - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (values[i][0] == "Applied*") {
      usedRange.getCell(i, 0).getEntireRow().delete(ExcelScript.DeleteShiftDirection.up)
    }
  }

}
```

I can not get it to work, should there be something else instead of the "*" after Applied in the last part of the script?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to turn your values into strings and then use the `search` function.

Example, I have these values in cells `A1:A5` ...

```
this string doesn't have it
this is test a string
this one has Test
another one without
nup, not this one
```

You'll need to adapt this but I created a script that looks like this ...

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook)
{
  let activeSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
  let range = activeSheet.getRange("A1:A5");
  let rangeValues = range.getValues();
  
  rangeValues.forEach(cellValue => {
    console.log(cellValue[0].toString().toLowerCase().search('test'));
  });
}
```

... and the output of to the console is this ...

[image: Result]

So as to avoid case, I set the string to lower case before searching but it's up to you if you want to honour case.

You can also use this approach ...

```
cellValue[0].toString().search(/test/i)
```

... to ignore case.

Bottom line, use `toString()` and then the `search()` function and it will return the position of the substring within your main string.

Anything greater than **-1** means the string exists.

If you want to test to see if the string starts with ***Applied*** then you'll need to check for all occurrences where the result of the search equals **0**.

Answer (score 1):

One option you can do is cast the values as an array of strings. So you would update a line like this:

```
//getting the values of the range
let values = usedRange.getValues();
```

To a line like this

```
//getting the values of the range
let values = usedRange.getValues() as string[][];
```

This may be faster than calling `toString()` on every element in the array.

After you did that you'd just have to update your conditional If line from this:

```
if (values[i][0] == "Applied*") {
```

To something like this:

```
if (values[i][0].toLowerCase().includes("applied")) {
```